# VS2010 cannot load msdia100.dll while debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2010

While I try to debug a program in VS2010 I get the following message:

[image: msdia100.dll cannot be loaded]

I have tried to:

- restart the computer

  move all files to a new sulotion

  debug a different program

  debug this program on a different computer

the first two mattered nothing, the lost two worked. 
what's wrong with my computer and how do I fix it?

I'm using VS2010 pro, running on win7.
I uploaded the project I tried debugging to [google drive](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3DAJEXg_yQhczRqWnNVUEpETGs/edit?usp=sharing), if any one wants to see it.

Comment: Your machine is pretty messed up when you get this message.  It is an important helper DLL for the debugger, it must be present in the common7\packages\debugger subdirectory.  Very unhealthy if it is missing or cannot be located by VS.  Fixing your machine is generally the number one thing to address, reinstalling vs is next.

Comment: Someone has been able to resolve this nasty problem with reregistering msdia100.dll - regsvr32 "%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger\msdia100.dll", however also if this resolve the problem, if you do not know how it happened, you are still in a bad situation.

Answer (score 1):

I started getting this error today. I checked multiple applications, and all failed. Visual Studio itself was crashing. The application was working 2 days ago. I had to copy msdia100.dll from my laptop and the run regsvr32 as described above. When I compared the files, they had the same time stamp and the same size, but the contents were completely different. No idea how the change happened. Everything appears to be working after replacing the DLL.